# C++ Floyd Triangle from range

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to create program which the output is:

```
Input : 7
1
23
456
7123
45671
234567
1234567
```

---

```
But the output i get is:

1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
```

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i, j, k;
cin >> i;
for (j=0; j<=i; ++j){
   for (k=1; k<=j; ++k){
     cout << k;
  }
   cout << "\n";
  }
return 0;
}
```

What should i fix in this to make this like the output on the top?
Thanks for help.

Comment: just add one variable and increment it and print it...not k

Comment: I dont understand the pattern you want to get. first the numbers are increasing until 7 and then start from 1 again, but in the last but one row they only go till 6 and then start from 1 in the last row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a couple changes.  First in

```
for (j=0; j<=i; ++j)
```

You start the loop at `0`.  That means that the iteration of the inner loop will never happen as you run until `k<=j` and since `k` starts at one which means you just print a blank line.  You need to start the loop at `1` instead of `0` tro fix that.

Second you need to add another variable to keep track of where in the sequence you are.  The good news is we can use modular math to make sure it wraps back to one for us.  Doing that would give you something like

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, j, k, output = 1;
    cin >> i;
    for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        for (k = 1; k <= j; ++k) {
            cout << output;
            if (output % i == 0) // wrap back to one once output == i
                output = 1;
            else
                ++output;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which gives you

```
1
23
456
7123
45671
234567
1234567
```

Comment: dont want to be too pedantic, but please note that your output is different from what is asked for in the question. Actually I dont see the pattern in what OP is asking for. Most likely it is just a typo

Comment: @tobi303 Pretty sure it is just a typo on the OP's part as everything else matches.

Comment: imho you should at least mention that. btw not my downvote

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to print either j or k.
The printed value is not dependant of them :

```
int main()
{
    int max, j, k, count = 0; //Add a count value
    std::cin >> max;
    for (j = 0; j <= max; ++j) {
        for (k = 1; k <= j; ++k) {
            count %= max; //If count exceed the entered number
            count++;
            std::cout << count;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It totally is, you're wrong here, you're not putting anything in stdin and the ouput is 100% correct

Comment: sorry, my fault, but please note that it [still doesnt match what OP is aking for](http://ideone.com/UiPAZ5), but thats most likely a typo in the question

Comment: Well.. without the error made in the question's output (line 6, there's two 1 in a row) i don't get whats wrong

Comment: Not sure why IDEone does not print the newline but do not a newline is printed on the first iteration when `j` is `0` as the inner loop never runs.

Answer (score 0):

In your inner loop variable `k` is always starts from 1

```
   for (k=1; k<=j; ++k){
        ^^^ 
     cout << k;
  }
```

Thus each output row also starts from 1 up to j.

A simple approach can look the following way. You declare a variable that is always incremented without depending on the indices of the loops.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        unsigned int n;

        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): ";

        if ( not ( std::cin >> n ) or ( n == 0 ) ) break;

        std::cout << '\n';

        for ( unsigned int i = 0, value = 0; i++ < n;  )
        {
            for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) 
            {
                std::cout << ++value ;
                value %= n;
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter 7 then its output can look the following way

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 7

1
23
456
7123
45671
234567
1234567

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

In this program there is introduced an auxiliary variable `value` that is always incremented and then evaluates like `value %= n`

In my opinion it is the most clear and simple approach.

If the program is not compiled in MS VC++ (due to setting on language extensions) then you can substitute this statement

```
if ( not ( std::cin >> n ) or ( n == 0 ) ) break;
```

for this one

```
if ( !( std::cin >> n ) || ( n == 0 ) ) break;
```